# Inserting a large table into a new table (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very large SQL Server table (220 million records) with size of 233GB. I need to export this table into a flat file and send it to another server through Putty which will directly insert this table into data warehouse.

This data warehouse has a specific schema how the data should be loaded (specific datatypes and length for each column).

First I need to do some validations by changing the datatype and data length of the columns in SQL Server. I used `alter table` to change the datatype and data length but ended up getting errors. So I'm trying to insert that table into a new one while using `SUBSTRING` and `CAST` functions on those columns which should stick to the data warehouse schema.

This is not possible because of space constraint in transaction log files drive and TempDB drive. I'm completely hopeless right now. Any alternative solutions to complete this task would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you create view on database. If yes transform data in your view and copy data to flat file from your view instead of table.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrabek Never tried that or thought of it. Let me give a try now

Answer (score 1):

I also work with a large table about this size on limited space. There are a few ways around it. But you must be cautious, you are probably getting errors because you ran out of physical space, which can potentially cause SQL to crash. When performing these operations, keep a close eye on disk free space and the log file size and how fast its growing. Cancel any operations that might result in maxing out your disk (preferably before you go past the point of no return, as the cancellation process takes time as well). First thing I would check, is your DB Recovery model set to Full or Simple? Setting to Simple can help reduce logging and using valuable temporary space.

When your dealing with very limited space, you need to watch your DB and log file sizes, of course. I know what I'm about to suggest usually frowned upon, but sometimes it's unavoidable. While attempting the next solutions, try to keep the DB and log files as low as possible using DBCC SHRINKFILE(). Make sure you properly calculate how much space is actually being used by the DB, and give a little padding room.

```
--Check free space in a file
USE DMS_DataCompare;
SELECT name ,size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS int)/128.0 AS AvailableSpaceInMB
FROM sys.database_files;


USE tempdb
DBCC SHRINKFILE (tempdev,1)

DBCC SHRINKFILE (templog,1)

USE Master;
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'MASTER',10000)

DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'MASTER_log',NOTRUNCATE)
```

One way to work at this is column by column. Can you delete any parts of the previous data table? If so, you can add a column with the same specifications as the schema you are trying to migrate to, then use an UPDATE to copy the data from the old column to the new, then delete the old column, then do a shrink file. Rinse and repeat.

Another thing to try, is there any data columns which have data you do not need? You could NULL those out, do a shrinkfile, and that would recover some valuable move space.

Another way would to be what a commenter posted, set up a view to force the data through the data types and sizes you need. I think you should try this first, as it makes this whole process read-only so your not messing with file sizes and logging. You can also write a procedure to work similarly to a view, that takes in two parameters, start and stop, than can be used to specify the range to pull. This can then be used in the export steps.

And as user1443098 posted, export in batches, not as a procedure but as a simple script. But this can be a pain to keep track of, especially trying to export in flat files, as you can quickly get lost in which file holds exactly what range, maybe name your file according to the range it holds. This option could potentially be useless if your data is currently live and changing.

Another option would be to back up the DB and restore it to a machine that does have the space. DB backups can be 1/10th their normal size after compressing it through backup (if you have a version of SQL that supports this).

Another would be a combination of two of the above. Create a table with the destination specs, then write a script to insert from the old table to the new, but in batches. After every batch, delete the same range out of the old table, and do a shrinkfile. Make sure you verify all data copied successfully into the new table first! This process could be very lengthy though, as each step involved will take time.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Oh That's a lot of info. Thanks man. Will let you know which one worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Insert into the new table in batches, say 1000,000 rows at a time.  That will help you control tempdb and log usage

Comment: I tried that too. Even to split that data it requires more space in TempDB drive.

Comment: Don't split the data in SQL.  In the program you are using to insert the data, read (from the flat file) some portion (e.g. 100.000 rows) at a time, insert those, then commit.  then do  the next 100,000 rows etc  until done

Comment: I forgot to mention this. I'm not importing this large table from a flat file. This table is created by joining two other tables in SQL.

Comment: So your problem is at this step? " I need to export this table into a flat file"  Then you could use SSIS running on a different server to do it (so as not to use up your tempdb) or simply get more tempdb space.